# Python pandas ambiguous time index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, time, average

see here my pandas Dataframe:

```
                       press222
datetime                       
2017-03-31 14:02:04  110.854683
2017-03-31 14:02:04  110.855759
2017-03-31 14:02:04  110.855103
2017-03-31 14:02:04  110.853790
2017-03-31 14:02:05  110.854034
2017-03-31 14:02:05  110.855103
2017-03-31 14:02:05  110.854683
2017-03-31 14:02:05  110.855698
2017-03-31 14:02:05  110.853851
2017-03-31 14:02:06  110.854385
2017-03-31 14:02:06  110.853905
2017-03-31 14:02:06  110.854988
2017-03-31 14:02:06  110.854988
2017-03-31 14:02:06  110.854988
```

You can see that I have got multiple values per second, but unfortunately the timestamps are in entire seconds (the logger did not spit out milliseconds), which makes it somehow ambiguous. Is there any way to get the mean of the values that belong to the "same second", so in this example a mean value for 14:02:04, one for 05 and one for 06?

(The actual dataframe is of course too long to do it manually...)

I tried the rolling mean like this:

```
df.rolling('S').mean()
```

And I get different values but still the same time column (=index). I'd like to keep only one row per second with the corresponding avg value.
Would appreciate your help - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on the index and call `mean`:

```
In [285]:
df.groupby(level=0).mean()

Out[285]:
                     press222      
datetime                           
2017-03-31 14:02:04      110.854834
2017-03-31 14:02:05      110.854674
2017-03-31 14:02:06      110.854651
```

So all duplicate values collapse into a single datetime entry

To do this on reading, you could read in chunks and do the above but if the duplicate entries span the chunks you'd still need to do the above but it will compress the first read df:

```
In [291]:    
import io
import pandas as pd
t="""datetime,press222      
2017-03-31 14:02:04,110.854683
2017-03-31 14:02:04,110.855759
2017-03-31 14:02:04,110.855103
2017-03-31 14:02:04,110.853790
2017-03-31 14:02:05,110.854034
2017-03-31 14:02:05,110.855103
2017-03-31 14:02:05,110.854683
2017-03-31 14:02:05,110.855698
2017-03-31 14:02:05,110.853851
2017-03-31 14:02:06,110.854385
2017-03-31 14:02:06,110.853905
2017-03-31 14:02:06,110.854988
2017-03-31 14:02:06,110.854988
2017-03-31 14:02:06,110.854988"""
chunks=[]
for chunk in pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0], chunksize=3):
    chunks.append(chunk.groupby(level=0).mean())
final_df = pd.concat(chunks)
final_df

Out[291]:
                     press222      
datetime                           
2017-03-31 14:02:04      110.855182
2017-03-31 14:02:04      110.853790
2017-03-31 14:02:05      110.854568
2017-03-31 14:02:05      110.854744
2017-03-31 14:02:06      110.854426
2017-03-31 14:02:06      110.854988
```

You can see that we still have duplicate entries but the df is smaller than if we didn't pre-process so we still need to perform the `groupby` again:

```
In [292]:
final_df.groupby(level=0).mean()

Out[292]:
                     press222      
datetime                           
2017-03-31 14:02:04      110.854486
2017-03-31 14:02:05      110.854656
2017-03-31 14:02:06      110.854707
```

Comment: Perfect! Is there a way to do that while reading the data from the file (with `read_csv`)? That's not mandatory, but would be nice to know

Comment: You could read in chunks and compress each chunk but if the entries span multiple chunks then you'd end up doing the above anyway. It really depends on file size here, I'll post an update

Comment: See update it helps reduce the initial read but you'd still need to `groupby` again

Comment: Ok, the dataframe is not this large, such that reading in chunks would be needed. But good to know anyway - thank you.